# Protected function not accessible in derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am making a simple C# console application to test inheritance but when I add 2 new classes and inherit one with another ( Mammal:Animal ) and make an object of mammal in the Program.cs class i-e

Program.cs

```
Mammal mam = new Mammal();

mam.see(only public function are showing of animal not the protected member of function)
```

Animal.cs

```
class Animal
{
protected void check()
{}
public void see()
{}
}
```

Mammal.cs

```
class Mammal:Animal
{
public void hair()
{}
}
```

Can't figure out why it is not allowing, as protected allows to inherit if they are in its hierarchy.

Comment: I'm afraid without seeing where the mistake in your code is, we won't be of much help. So post your code.

Comment: Show your code, this question is useless without it. Also, it generally makes no sense to have class with a plural name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code *within* `Mammals` has access to protected members of `Animals`, but only via an expression of type `Mammals` or a subtype.

From *outside* the class - which I assume this is - there's no access to protected members.

From section 3.5.3 of the C# 5 specification (emphasis mine):

> When a `protected` instance member is accessed outside the program text of the class in which it is declared, and when a `protected internal` instance member is accessed outside the program text of the program in which it is declared, **the access must take place within a class declaration that derives from the class in which it is declared**. Furthermore, the access is required to take place through an instance of that derived class type or a class type constructed from it.

(As noted by Jonathan Reinhart, you almost certainly want these types to be called `Mammal` and `Animal`, by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

Below is the way to access protected methods in derived class

```
     class Animal
     {
       protected void check()
       {}
       public void see()
       {}
     }

    class Mammal:Animal
    {
      public void CallSee()
        {
            Animal obja = new Animal();
            obja.see();
        }
    }
```

Now you can create instance of class Mammal and call method callSee which will in turn call see method of Animal. As above answer suggestion proctected members are not accesible outside derived class. It can only be accessible in derived class

In Main Function write below code.

```
    Static Main()
    {
      Mammal objm= new Mammal();
      objm.CallSee();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `protected` access modifier can be accessed only from within the declaring class or its sub classes...only `public` and `internal` makes a method accessible from outside